# Problema ao dividir um vetor de String em C

Tags: c, array, string

Estou fazendo um programa que necessita que ache a metade de um vetor de string, porém essa metade não pode cortar nenhuma palavra, então essa metade teria que ser necessariamente o próximo espaço encontrado depois da metade. Logo após achar essa metade o programa deve dividir o vetor em 2 vetores de string. Um com a primeira parte e outro com a segunda.

Até agora o que eu tenho é isso aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void DivideString(char *Texto, char *Metade1, char *Metade2, int tamanho,int 
metade){
int i;
for(i = 0; i < metade; i++){
    Metade1[i] = Texto[i];
}
for(i=metade; i<tamanho; i++){
    Metade2[i] = Texto[i];
}
}

int CalculaMeio(int metade, char *Texto){
while(Texto[metade]!=' '){
    metade++;
}
return metade;
}

int main(){
char *Texto, *Metade1, *Metade2;
int i;

Texto = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));

Texto = "Testando como funcionam strings em c para trabalho";

int tamanho = strlen(Texto), metade = tamanho/2;

printf("tamanho: %d  metade: %d\n",tamanho, metade);

metade = CalculaMeio(metade, Texto);

printf("nova metade: %d\n",metade );

Metade1=(char*)malloc(metade*sizeof(char));
Metade2=(char*)malloc((tamanho-metade)*sizeof(char));

DivideString(Texto, Metade1, Metade2, tamanho, metade);

printf("%s\n",Metade1 );
printf("%s\n",Metade2 );
return 0;
}
```

Ao executar esse programa se tem o seguinte:

### [image: Aparantemente dando erro por não estar printando a segunda parte da frase]

Como da pra ver pela imagem o programa printa o primeiro vetor corretamente porém o segundo vetor não é printado.

Seria esse algum problema com o buffer?

Comment: E se a string não apresentar espaços ?

Comment: Ela sempre apresentaria espaços.É pra dividir um texto normal, com espaços com mais de 1 palavra...  Igual o do programa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua função `DivideString()` pode ser implementada de maneira bem mais simples, veja só:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void DivideString( const char * txt, char * m1, char * m2 )
{
    int tam = strlen(txt);
    int meio = tam / 2;

    while( txt[meio] && !isspace(txt[meio]) )
        meio++;

    *m1 = '\0';
    *m2 = '\0';

    strncat( m1, txt, meio );
    strncat( m2, txt + meio + 1, tam - meio );
}
```

Testando:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char texto[] = "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma.";

    char metade1[100];
    char metade2[100];

    DivideString( texto, metade1, metade2 );

    printf( "Texto: %s (Tamanho: %ld)\n", texto, strlen(texto) );
    printf( "Metade1: %s (Tamanho: %ld)\n", metade1, strlen(metade1) );
    printf( "Metade2: %s (Tamanho: %ld)\n", metade2, strlen(metade2) );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Texto: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma. (Tamanho: 35)
Metade1: O rato roeu a roupa (Tamanho: 19)
Metade2: do rei de Roma. (Tamanho: 15)
```

Veja funcionando do [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/rFGjmY)

Comment: Muito obrigado :) Funcionou bem aqui